# Call to the controller from Ui is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im trying to call to action like following and I got error http404

I want to call to the following :

Action name:check

Controller name :user

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="form-group" >
    @using (Html.BeginForm("check", "user", new { Name = Model.Name }))
    {
        <input type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("check", "user")'"  value="Check"  />
        <span id='result'></span>
      }  
</div>
```

Comment: Your form will post to Check/User without using the button's on click event (if input type is submit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take Input type as submit. You have already specified Controller and action name in form.

```
<div class="form-group" >
  @using (Html.BeginForm("check", "user", FormMethod.Post, new { Name = Model.Name }))
  {
    <input type="submit" value="Check"  />
    <span id='result'></span>
  }  
</div>
```

And Your Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Check(string name)
{
 // do stuff
}
```

OR You can try:

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" value="btnText" onclick="window.location.href='/Controller/Action'">
```

Comment: The problem is that I alredy have button for save which is type submit and when I add also submit to the check it run the create action...

Comment: HI pawan I read this thanks but didnt figure out what is the delta btween ,can you help?

Comment: @shopiaT Try This:  
if (HttpContext.Request.Form["btnSave"] != null)
{
   // Do Stuff
}
else if (HttpContext.Request.Form["SecondButton"] != null)
{
  // do stuff
}

Comment: I think you answer the question but now I put the specific issue (open new post just now ) 1:1 please see if you can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56348/discussion-between-pawan-and-shopia-t).

Answer (score 0):

Try this--->

```
 <div class="form-group" >
@using (Html.BeginForm("check", "user", new { Name = Model.Name }))
{
    <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("check", "user")'"         value="Check"  />
    <span id='result'></span>
  }
```